# The link address '$management' did not match any of the expected formats

Tags: c#, azure, mqtt

I'm trying to build a function that will listen to the incoming MQTT messages in my Azure IoT hub.

I'm clueless why I keep getting errors and I'm not sure what I'm missing, I just have the base code as I just wanted to test if it would reach the breakpoint and if there was indeed a message.

So, my code is the following:
`Function1.cs`

```
public static class Function1
{

    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "connectionString", ConsumerGroup = "FuncGroup")]EventData message, ILogger log)
    {
        string hello = "hey";
        log.LogInformation($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.ToArray())}");
    }
}
```

`local.settings.json`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "connectionString": "Endpoint=sb://[hub url].azure-devices.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=[username];SharedAccessKey=[password];"
  }
}
```

When I run the function I get always the same error:

> The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.
> System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (The link address
> '$management' did not match any of the expected formats.
> (messages/events)) (The link address '$management' did not match any
> of the expected formats. (messages/events)). System.Private.CoreLib:
> The link address '$management' did not match any of the expected
> formats. (messages/events). System.Private.CoreLib: The link address
> '$management' did not match any of the expected formats.

I have also tried to add the `EntityPath` to the end of the connection string but it was unsuccessfully, I would just get this error:

> The path to an Event Hub may be specified as part of the connection
> string or as a separate value, but not both.  Please verify that your
> connection string does not have the `EntityPath` token if you are
> passing an explicit Event Hub name. (Parameter 'connectionString')'

Any idea of what I could be missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is not with the Function App code.

Please check whether you have routed the data to built-in endpoint of the IoT Hub Consumer Group. This becomes necessary when you have multiple routes created on your IoT Hub.

To create this route - Add another route on IoT Hub with Endpoint as **events** under Built in Endpoint

[image]

Comment: It was close to the solution, I needed to do some additional things as well like register for the EventGrid on azure, setup properly my event hub in the custom endpoints and other stuff that I don't remember right now